# Parsing out date_entered field to capture TIME 'hh:mm:ss' based on time range

Tags: oracle, plsql

Based on the date_entered column, which is a data_type of 'DATE' how would I parse out the data to pull the time.

Values in the `DATE_ENTERED` field (`DATA_TYPE` is `DATE`) looks like this `5/15/2015 8:43:04 PM`

I need to run queries based on when `DATE_ENTERED` is `between 05/15/2015 8:00 AM` and `05/15/2015 10:00 AM`

I then need to incorporate that into a PL/SQL script that will run every 2 hours with the last two hours as the filter. My best explanation of this would be where it grabs the current date and time, and pulls 2 hours back, every 2 hours. This will allow it to run at 8am, 10am, 12pm, 2pm etc and have the last 2 hours of new entries in the query. For instance 10am run time will include results for items entered in from 8:00am until 10:00am

Comment: You don't need to "parse out the data to pull the time" -- you can simply subtract the required duration from `SYSDATE()`.

Comment: How would I pull the 2 hour duration from `SYSDATE`? Would it be something along the lines of `dateadd(-2, hh,SYSDATE())`? How would I do that in Oracle though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
WHERE date_entered BETWEEN sysdate - interval '2' hour
                       AND sysdate
```

Assuming `date_entered` never contains future dates

```
WHERE date_entered >= sysdate - interval '2' hour
```

Depending on exactly what you need (and why you're running the query), you may want to truncate the `date` to the hour or minute so that you're always comparing against data from the top of the hour

```
WHERE date_entered >= trunc(sysdate - interval '2' hour, 'HH24')
```

Depending on why you are doing this, however, keep in mind that you may miss data if you're running every 2 hours.  If I insert a row at, say 3:59:59 pm, your job starts runs at 4:00:00 pm (looking for data between 2 and 4) and at 6 pm (looking for data between 4 and 6), and I commit at 4:00:01 pm, then neither execution of the job will return this row.

Comment: Justin, Thank you for your response, I was a little worried I was not 'wording' it correctly and clearly, however I just tried your method and that is exactly what I am looking for. This will be part of a PL/SQL script that will run this query and auto email the results.